# HttpRequest is null when I run an azure function

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I want to upload files into azure blob storage using AzureFunctions in c#.

So this is my azure function :

```
public static class AppartementFunc
{

    [Function("AppartementFunc")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        string Connection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
        string containerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ContainerName");
        Stream myBlob = new MemoryStream();
        var file = req.Form.Files["File"];
        myBlob = file.OpenReadStream();
        var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(Connection, containerName);
        var blob = blobClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
        await blob.UploadAsync(myBlob);
        return new OkObjectResult("file uploaded successfylly");
    }
}
```

I tried to test this function from postman like this :

[image]

but this line `var file = req.Form.Files["File"]` trigger an error :

```
`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

req was null.`
```

I dont know why the HttpRequest req is NULL !
Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: Can you show the exact error message including stack trace? Does it really say "req was null"?

Comment: yes it is null, I verified that with debugging the req is always null.

Comment: Are you using the isolated worker hosting model?  What version of .NET?

Comment: I'am using .NET 7.0 isolated

Comment: @Hiba thought so; you can't use `HttpRequest` directly.  See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you're using code for Azure Functions "in-process" hosting model while the application is actually hosted via "isolated worker" model.

For Azure Functions Isolated Worker hosting model, the `HttpTrigger` parameter should be of type `HttpRequestData` and HTTP response return types should be `Task<HttpResponseData>`

[Differences Between In-Process & Isolated Worker Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-in-process-differences)

[Guide for running C# Azure Functions in an isolated worker process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide)

Comment: Yes Thank you, now I understand

Answer (score 1):

Since middle of 2023 it is possible to use ASP.NET Core integration in Isolated Model. So now, it is perfectly possible to handle json and files using `HttpRequest` and other familiar classes.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-aspnet-core-integration-in-azure-functions-net-isolated-model/

See the guide to migrate here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#aspnet-core-integration

In Postman, you can organize your request in Files and Data like this, using multipart/form-data:

[image]

On Azure Functions Isolated Model code you can handle the parameters like this:

[image]

We can see from the picture above that we can use the data independently.

I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: That's correct, it's possible since August 2023. It's all detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#http-trigger but it's a pity Microsoft doesn't say which is the best approach: To go with the extra dependencies and do as you say or the 'old' way. They present them as equivalent...